# How can I call my function multiple times using setInterval?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to do a for loop 10 times and i wrote setInterval to call my function again but it does not work. My for loop turns only ten. So how can i do?

```
function randomThumbNews() {
        for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
        $.ajax({
            type: "get", url: "Home/Oku", data: {},
            success: function (data) {
                $("#thumbNews_" + i).html(data);
            }
        });
         }
    }
setInterval(randomThumbNews, 3000);
```

Comment: Did you check the error console? The code as you've posted it is erroneous.

Comment: You've put `setInterval()` in an object literal, which is invalid syntax. I'm surprised that code runs at all.

Comment: I have edit my question and my script

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to accomplish a little better? You say you're trying to run it 10 times, but it runs 10 times?

Comment: This is the usual JS n00b issue of expecting `i` in the closure to be at execution time as it was when declaring the closure.  The selector evaluates to `#thumbnews_10` every time is what he's trying to say.

Comment: A little off topic, but the code you have posted is very inefficient. It would be better to send one request every x amount of time to return 10 news items (or whatever you're getting), rather than do 10 ajax requests every x amount of time!

Comment: I'm trying to run it 10 times but it runs 1 time. And when i check my div id to control for loop, my div id is 10 the others are missing i mean this loop return just only one value

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this -- when

```
function (data) {
     $("#thumbNews_" + i).html(data);
 }
```

Is called the loop has already finshed so `i` will always be 10.

You will only see results posted to one of your `<div>`s

This will fix it since function parameters don't have closure:

```
function ajaxAndSet(counter)
{
  $.ajax({
           type: "get", 
           url: "Home/Oku",
           data: {},
           success: function (data) 
           {
              $("#thumbNews_" + counter).html(data);
           }
        });
)

function randomThumbNews() 
{
   for(var i=0;i<10;i++)
   {
       ajaxAndSet(i);
   }
}

setInterval(randomThumbNews, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "get", url: "Home/Oku", data: {},
    context: i, /* NEW - this value comes to your success callback as 'this' */
    success: function (data) {
        $("#thumbNews_" + this).html(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: techfoobar - this would still have the same issue I believe.